# Textfield and Go Button

Tags: html, textfield

I would like to place search textfield and the Go button side by side.

It looks aligned equally in Moz, Opera, IE8, Safari but not in IE7. IE7 shows 1px gap in height.

How it can be done for IE7?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, sounds like the old [IE box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

You'll probably need to conditionally include a separate stylesheet for IE7, and set the margin, padding and border to 0 (you might also need to play with border-collapse to get it to work).

Might also be worth setting your DOCTYPE to something nice and strict (XHTML STRICT maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the doctype first if you haven't already. Usually fixes a lot a crappy ie bugs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
```